# Can some one explain how x pass into function f

Tags: python, function, class

```py
def f(obj):
    print('attr =', obj.attr)

class Foo:
    attr = 100
    attr_val = f

x = Foo()
print(x.attr)
x.attr_val()
```

Output:

```
100
attr = 100
```

I got this code from real python but I don't understand how `x` is pass into function `f`.

Can someone explain that to me, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why ask a question and get a -1?

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a class object when you are doing `x.attr_val()` it automatically takes itself and provides it as a first argument to the function (often arguments like this are named `self`).

Comment: right, I got confused because f got assigned to attr_val. If f is defined inside the Foo class then it is obvious. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`attr_val` is what is called an **instance method**. When your `Foo` class calls it, it passes the object as first argument automatically, effectively running: `f(x)`

If you were using a custom `__init__` method, the standard practice would be to pass the `self` variable to indicate this self-reference.

Thus, a more verbose variant would be:

```
def f(obj):
    print('attr =', obj.attr)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 100
    def attr_val(self):
        f(self) # or "return f(self)"

x = Foo()
x.attr_val()
# attr = 100
```

Comment: right, I got confused because f got assigned to attr_val. If f is defined inside the Foo class then it is obvious. thank you very much.